# Trying to format response for API but i don't know how

Tags: go, go-gorm

hello developers i recently hit a wall trying to create slightly advance query with many 2 many relationship and belongs to relationship and i was successfully fetching them all with GORM , but i want to format the response to my won structure and i can't do it here my query i gorm

```
var p []modules.Posts
tm := modules.Tags{}
db.First(&tm , tagID)
//tag and posts has many 2 many rel
//post belongs to user 
tagMaps := db.Model(&tm).Preload("TagMaps").Preload("User").Related(&p,"Posts")
```

i'm trying to format the response to something like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "post_id",
        "title": "post_title",
        "image" :" post_image",

        "tags":[
            {"name" : "tag_name" , "id" : "tag_id"},
            {"name" : "tag_name" , "id" : "tag_id"},
            {"name" : "tag_name" , "id" : "tag_id"}

        ],
        "user":{
            "id": "user_id",
            "avatar": " user_avatar"
        }

    }
]
```

this what the gorm response look like right know

```
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "thos lore for other users lorem 2",
    "image": "",
    "User": {
        "ID": 1,
        "avatar": "url",
        "user_name": "user 5",
        "email": "newadmin@test.com",
        "password": "password",
        "status": "pea",
        "google_id": "google",
        "facebook_id": "face",
        "account_type": "fb",
        "CreatedAt": "2020-04-02T20:35:38+02:00",
        "UpdatedAt": "2020-04-02T20:35:38+02:00",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "Posts": null
    },
    "UserRefer": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-04-02T20:36:05+02:00",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-02T20:36:05+02:00",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "TagMaps": [{
            "id": 1,
            "tag_name": "asda",
            "CreatedAt": "2020-04-15T23:25:05+02:00",
            "UpdatedAt": "2020-04-17T21:39:26+02:00",
            "DeletedAt": null,
            "Posts": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "tag_name": "name",
            "CreatedAt": "2020-04-15T23:25:05+02:00",
            "UpdatedAt": "2020-04-17T21:39:26+02:00",
            "DeletedAt": null,
            "Posts": null
        }
    ]
  },
```

this my current structs

```
type Posts struct {
    ID           uint        `json: "id"`
    Title        string      `json: "title"`
    Image        string      `json: "image"`
    User         *User `gorm: "foreignkey:UserRefer"` // use UserRefer as foreign key
    UserRefer uint
    CreatedAt    time.Time   `json: "created_at"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time   `json: "updated_at"`
    DeletedAt    *time.Time  `sql: "index" json: "deleted_at"`
    TagMaps      []Tags `gorm: "many2many:tag_maps;association_autoupdate:false;association_autocreate:false;"`
}

type Tags struct {
    ID        uint   `gorm: "primary_key" json: "id"`
    Name      string `json: "tag_name"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql: "index"`

    Posts        []*Posts `gorm: "many2many:tag_maps"`
}

type User struct {
    ID          uint   `gorm: "primary_key"`
    Avatar      string `json: "avatar" `
    UserName    string `json: "user_name"`
    Password    string `json: "password"`
    Bio         string `json: "bio"`
    GoogleID    string `json: "google_id"`
    FacebookID  string `json: "facebook_id"`
    AccountType string `json: "account_type"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
    DeletedAt   *time.Time `sql: "index"`

    // Relationship
    Posts   *Posts `gorm: "PRELOAD:false"`
}
```

any advice will be appropriated and my level in go isn't that good i started playing with like month ago

Comment: please provide more information, your goal is not clear

Comment: done any more info needed ?

Comment: Transforming one data structure into an other is basic programming. YOu just have to _do_ it, there is nothing to "know" here.

Comment: did you read the last line  in my post  i said  "my level in go isn't that good i started playing with like month ago"

Comment: You can define custom structs that match the desired json structure, then after you retrieve your gorm models you convert those models into the new structs, this you would do in a loop manually, object to object, field to field. After you're done with the conversion you can json-marshal the result and you're done.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks man i will try this , i did try use scan but it doesn't work on relationships  only one the first layer of the response

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you trying to achieve but GORM response is not so far from the one you need.

Can you try to add more encoding json tag to your structs, ie:

- to ignore the "CreatedAt" field

```
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"-"`
```

- to transform "User" into "user" (works for TagMaps too)

```
    User         *User `gorm: "foreignkey:UserRefer" json:"user"`
```

By the way, there is also json:",omitempty" to ignore empty field

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal